2N5109 Replacement
I am constructing a pre-amp for the HF range and the transistor mentioned is the 2N5109. It is not readily available and was thinking about a suitable replacement which is readily available from large stockists e.g. Mouser or Arrow.
Any suggestions would be welcome,
Thanks,
Joseph

Most suitable replacements are surface-mount rather than 2N5109 thru-hole. Are you adaptable to package type?

There was a replacement from NTE in the same TO-39 case but as NTE is now gone for good you are out of luck. There are modern examples available as SMD that may be acceptable for you. With very few exceptions, this types of RF transistors only tolerate low Vce voltages (typ. 12...15V).

It is best to post the amp's schematic diagram and any other design details so that we know what aspects of the transistor spec are important in that design.

the question really is whether it makes sense to go with a preamp design that's so prehistoric, or whether both component and RF design technology have moved on and you could build a better and easier preamp if you don't stick to whatever schematic you have at hand, but go for something more modern?

So, please follow @RyujiAB1WX's advice and post the schematic, but equally important, also post as specific a specification for what the preamp needs to fulfill – input and output powers, gain, the specific range within the HF spectrum that it needs to work at, and if you can come up with that, any specifications on acceptable noise figures and intermodulation products would help, as well! You can't just replace a transistor with another without knowing what it's used for.

... although we can guess what kind of circuit it may be... there are only a couple of types of popular wideband HF preamps that require big transistors... and I have some transistors to use in place of 2N5109... but I don't want to answer without sufficient details with the OP question. @MarcusMüller
